# Convert unusual Time & Datestring to JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, date

I need to convert a string to a JavaScript-Date

Examples of the source-strings

```
Wed, 01 Apr 2015 07:30:42 CEST
Mon, 23 Mar 2015 08:00:15 CET
```

I tried parsing it with Date.parse and creating a new Date from it but it is not working, JS throws an "Invalid Date" error.

What is the best way to convert this string? Do I have to go all RegEx over it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming your examples are strictly adhered to, regex would be ovekill. First split the string on spaces, commas, or colons. Then call the Date function with the components in the required order.

Comment: Without the trailing time zone abbreviations, those are working date strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timezones are not valid for `Date.parse()`

So you have to replace your timezones, something like this:

```
var dateString = "Wed, 01 Apr 2015 07:30:42 CEST";

dateString = dateString.replace("CET", "GMT+1");
dateString = dateString.replace("CEST", "GMT+2");

var date = Date.parse(dateString);
console.log(date);
// => 1427873322000
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use your answer since it will keep the timezone-information.